# numpy C-API: scalar multiplication in C

Tags: python, c, numpy, c-api

How can I perform an element-wise multiplication of a numpy-nd-array with an arbitrary double-scalar in C?

I'm searching for a api-function like this:

```
// C-code
PyArray_MultiplyWithScalar((PyArrayObject *) myarray, double scalar_value);
```

corresponding to pure numpy:

```
# pure python
myarray = myarray * scalar_value
```

My current (bad) solution is to iterate over all entries and perform the normalization manually.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. Use `NpyIter_New` to iterate through the array. Otherwise you can convert the scalar_value to an array of course and call the ufunc through python.

Comment: Ah, and you need to set the correct flags, i.e. `NPY_ITER_GROWINNER` and `NPY_ITER_EXTERNAL_LOOP` for best speeds, which gets a bit more involved but it might be worth to learn.

Comment: I've seen all these iterators with the flags but I'm hoping for a better/shorter solution :-)  
I think that increasing the optimized iterator costs a functioncall...

Comment: no it doesn't with external_loop. With it, you will get the innermost loop for yourself to implement, and that innermost loop will often be the whole array.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the right answer to your question, but if you do a loop in C that should be as fast as it gets, I would even think faster than calling a python api function if you do it right. Doing it that way you can even edit the array in place without the need for additional memory.

Comment: I think/hope that numpy has it's own **best way** to iterate over all entries without the need for additional memory.